# What is the confidence interval for the mean of the population?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

Let $X$~$Exp(\lambda)$ then
$f$($x$;$\lambda$) $=$ $\lambda$e$^{-\lambda x}$ $I$$_{(0,\infty)}$($x$). Obtain  confidence interval for the mean of the population.

To do this, we need to remember a few facts about the gamma distribution. More specifically, If $Y=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$, where the $X_i$'s are independent $Exp(\lambda)$ random variables then $Y \sim Gamma(n, \theta)$. Thus, the random variable $Q$ is defined as $Q=\theta (X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n)$ has a $ Q \sim Gamma(n, 1)$ distribution. Let us define $\gamma_{p,n}$ as follows. For any $p \in [0,1]$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we define $\gamma_{p,n}$ as the real value for which $P(Q > \gamma_{p,n})=p,$ where $ Q \sim Gamma(n, 1)$ the Confidence interval is $\frac{\gamma_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2},n-1}}{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n}, \frac{\gamma_{\frac{\alpha}{2},n-1}}{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n}$. Is this right?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that

$$Y=2\lambda\Sigma_i X_i\sim \chi_{(2n)}^2$$

Now $Y$ is your pivotal qty so first calculate the 2 quantiles of $Y$ with paper tables or calculator and then you can easy find the confidence bounds for $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ solving the double inequality in $\frac{1}{\lambda}$.

Thus, setting $a,b$ the 2 quantiles of the $\chi_{(2n)}^2$ you get

$$a<2\lambda \Sigma_i X_i<b$$

That is

$$\frac{2\Sigma_i X_i}{b}<\frac{1}{\lambda}<\frac{2\Sigma_i X_i}{a}$$

Comment: Why for $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ ?

Comment: So my answer is wrong?

Comment: @Bbkuh bbniya: you said to be interested in confidence interval for the mean. If the density is $\lambda e ^{-\lambda x}$ as you posted, the expectation is $E[X]=\frac{1}{\lambda}$

Comment: Yeah you're right. What is the confidence interval for the mean of the population can you show me cause i'm solving it an hour ago

Comment: Can you please help me?

Comment: @Bbkuh bbniya: added full solution.  If the answer has been useful you can mark it as accepted